# The HTML5 audio tag keeps pausing without being paused, and will only continue if muted. Some won't even play anymore

Tags: html5-audio

See I have this issue when I am listening to audio. Whenever I go to another tab, the audio stops unexpectedly without being paused. And when I mute it, the playback continues... and when I unmute it, the playback stops. This issue also happens to other audio files as well... it's been bugging me alot... is there a fix for it?

I tried moving to another tab, and the audio stopped but it wasn't paused... It only showed the pause icon... you know the two dual lines... and when you mute the volume, the playback continues... it really has been bugging me all this time. I want this bug to be fixed... it's not fair... Can you see if you can help me?

Comment: Include the HTML in your question.